# How to install documentation for javax.servlet in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, servlets, documentation

I have a Spring project in IntelliJ. Usually when I click on *Download source and/or documentation* in the Maven panel, all needed documentation is installed and I can access it from the source code. This is not the case for the `javax.servlet` package.

How can I install this documentation ?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a Spring project using Tomcat, the `javax.servlet` classes are in the `tomcat-embed-core` library. This library has no javadoc jar file available on Maven Central. The solution is to go to :

`File -> Project structure -> Libraries -> org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core...`

and click on `Specify Documentation URL...`

and set the value `https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs`

Comment: Good one. Thanks for the self-answer. Perhaps you could generalise the question and answer so that it is applicable to any library which does not ship with a source jar?

Comment: It's the documentation jar that is missing and not the source jar, and this case is a bit specific because `javax.servlet` has multiple implementation and is defined in a specification. I'm not sure there is something to gain in generalizing the answer.